# latex: refer a subsection, looking for IV.B instead of IV.II

Tags: reference, label, latex

I get a problem when using \ref to refer a subsection. The titles of sections and subsections start with Latin number (I, II, III...) and English letter (A, B, C...) respectively, but when I refer the subsection, I only get something like 'IV.II' or 'IV.III'. I hope to get the form as 'IV.B' or 'IV.C'.

I have checked online, but don't find anything about this problem. Could someone help? thanks!

The packages I am using are:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference,letterpaper,twocolumn,twoside]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Needed for typesetting math
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Needed for including graphics
\usepackage{geometry}   % Used for setting the page layout
\usepackage{verbatim}   % Useful for program listings. Defines the
\usepackage{color}      % Load it if color is used in text. There also
\usepackage{amsthm}         %  amsthm package enabled to type theorems and lemmas
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}    %hua xie
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}       %hollow
\usepackage[lined,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}   %finish the 'NOTATION table'
\usepackage{subfigure}  %for figures arrangement
\geometry{left=0.625in,right=0.625in,top=0.75in,bottom=1in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\Tau}{\mathrm{T}}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\eg}{e.$\,$g., }
\usepackage{float}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your recursive definition of `\thesubsection` is incorrect. Instead, you need

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
```

in order to obtain a `III.A` style subsection numbering.